# apache/php error log filling up regarding default values

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

Watching my error log via csf and this is coming in a few times per second

[image]

yet line 1716 contains only default values

[image]

Why would this be happening?

CLOUDLINUX 6.8 x86_64 standard  WHM 60.0 (build 28)

Comment: If you're not going to change it, comment it out. That's the default setting anyway.

Comment: Maybe you should use a string instead? `mimetype= '^text...'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by simply commenting it out.